# Https connection in java

Tags: java, ssl, https, tomcat

I have successfully generated a keystore using

> keytool -genkeypair -alias SomeAlias -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keystore NAME.keystore -storetype JKS

placed it in tomcat config dir and updated server.xml file enabling 8443 port listening.

So i can access https://localhost:8443/MyApp

But when i am trying to POST some data from https://localhost:8443/MyApp to https://localhost:8443/MyApp

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

my POST function:

```
    public void HttpsPostData(String data, URL url){
    try {
        String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(encodedData);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(inputLine); 
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Sender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to trust the server certificate, even if it was localhost. Probably the easiest way is to use a Java application called [InstallCert](http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java). See a blog post [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification).

Quick steps:

1. Compile the InstallCert.java with `javac InstallCert.java`.
2. Call `java InstallCert localhost:8443`, trust the certificate and InstallCert will produce a file called `jssecacerts`.
3. Copy `jssecacerts` to your JDK directory under the `jre/lib/security` directory.

and the program should be able to trust the certificate.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in runtime without touching java.home?

Comment: @EirNym Apparently yes (see: http://exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/TrustAll.html). I would only recommend this for testing purposes, because this basically makes the SSL useless.

Comment: So I can easily make X509TrustManager with partial trust!

Comment: @EirNym if you want to use a different truststore (other than `cacerts` in the JRE home directory), you can use the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` (and related) system properties.